# Writing a function in which variable names change according to catagory and entire function repeated n times R

Tags: r, function

I have written a long piece of code in R in which I do some data handling on taxonomic data. The problem is that it repeats numerous times, first on the basis of taxa, that is Domain, Phylum, Class etc. and then for 7 sites. I want to be able to place this in a function so that if I change a piece of code that I don't have to copy, paste and adjust at each section of the code.

I have tried placing the code in a function myself, however apparently in R you can't name a variable outside a function, assign to it inside a function and then use it again outside the function... As far as I understand.

Here is my attempt for the function:

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)    
prepare_taxa_data <- function(data, taxa, variable_1, variable_2, site) {

  variable_1 <- count(data$taxa)
  variable_2 <- colnames(variable_1)[2] <- site
  variable_1$perc <- variable_1$freq*100/sum(variable_1$freq)
  variable_1$site <- site
  variable_2 <- top_n(variable_1, domain_n, variable_1$freq)
  variable_2$perc <- variable_2$freq*100/sum(variable_2$freq)

}

prepare_taxa_data(data_1, Domain, Domain_count_1.1, Domain_count_1, "Site_1")
prepare_taxa_data(data_1, Phylum, Phylum_count_1.1, Phylum_count_1, "Site_1")
```

So now I also want to be able to keep adding to the numbers of the variable so that applying the function becomes something like this for the next site:

```
prepare_taxa_data(data_2, Domain, Domain_count_2.1, Domain_count_2, "Site_2")
prepare_taxa_data(data_2, Phylum, Phylum_count_2.1, Phylum_count_2, "Site_2")
```

So in the end the function should have the result such as this but you can you how much of a pain it is to write this for 6 levels of taxa and repeat for 7 sites.

```
Domain_count_1.1 <- count(data_1$Domain)
Domain_count_1 <- colnames(Domain_count_1.1)[2] <- "Site_1"
Domain_count_1.1$perc <- Domain_count_1.1$freq*100/sum(Domain_count_1.1$freq)
Domain_count_1.1$site <- "Site 1"
Domain_count_1 <- top_n(Domain_count_1.1, domain_n, Domain_count_1.1$freq)
Domain_count_1$perc <- Domain_count_1$freq*100/sum(Domain_count_1$freq)

Phylum_count_1.1 <- count(data_1$Phylum)
Phylum_count_1.1$perc <- Phylum_count_1.1$freq*100/sum(Phylum_count_1.1$freq)
Phylum_count_1.1$site <- "Site 1"
Phylum_count_1 <- top_n(Phylum_count_1.1, phyla_n, Phylum_count_1.1$freq)
Phylum_count_1$perc <- Phylum_count_1$freq*100/sum(Phylum_count_1$freq)
```

Here is a very simple example of what the data frame would look like. Just imagine each domain or phyla entry is the name of some difficult to pronounce organism.

```
x <- c("domain1", "domain2", "domain3", "domain4")
a <- c("phylum1", "phylum2", "phylum3", "phylum4")
b <- c("class1", "class2", "class3", "class4")
c <- c("order1", "order2", "order3", "order4")

df_site_1 <- data.frame(x,a,b,c)
names(df_site_1) <- c("Domain", "Phylum", "Class", "Order")
```

Comment: Can you post a some of the dataframe that contains the data?

Comment: Also, in R, you want to avoid many objects flooding your global environment. With more context we can help set up a named (indexable) list to contain these five elements per site and level.

Comment: @FG7 Sure! Please see the bottom of my edit!